# Custom Chart Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel chart whose X-axis values are 5000, 10000, 15000 and so-on but I want them to be like 1,2,3,...  i.e. divide them by 5000.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the axis options and chose to show by thousands:

Right click the axis > Format Axis... > Axis Options > Display units > change None to Thousands

[image]

Another way would be to add a column next to your column containing the thousands divide all by a thousand in your new column and use that new column for your chart